# How do I use VSCode css.customData for postcss syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to extend `postcss` autocomplete with my custom colors/fonts/etc variables via [custom-data-format](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/02/24/custom-data-format). I can generate [JSON like this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/blob/master/samples/helloworld/css.css-data.json) in my UI Kit easily.

The problem is - I use `postcss` as syntax for `*.css` files therefore I'm unable to use autocomplete values as they're defined for css only in `css.css-data.json`. if I choose `css` syntax for those files - autocomplete works fine, but it obviously disables other PostCSS language features/syntax highlight etc.

How do I configure customData so whatever I define in `css.css-data.json` will work with `postcss` syntax?

I tried `postcss.customData` without any luck. Easily reproducible on this [sample workspace](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/tree/master/samples/helloworld)

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of now postcss syntax is not supported (you can track [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data/issues/12) for info), here's workaround to solve autocompletion :

[image]

You can achieve **sort-of-autocomplete** via snippets - here I've generated json named `my-autocomplete.code-snippets` and simply put it into `workspace/.vscode`:

```
    {
    "my-ui-kit-variables": {
        "scope": "postcss",
        "prefix": "$my-ui-kit",
        "body": "${2|$my-ui-kit-color-white,$my-ui-kit-color-transparent,$my-ui-kit-color-black,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-10,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-100,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-200,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-250,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-300,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-400,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-500,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-600,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-700,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-night-800,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-10,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-100,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-200,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-250,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-300,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-400,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-500,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-600,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-700,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-800,$my-ui-kit-color-gray-day-900,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-100,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-200,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-300,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-400,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-500,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-600,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-700,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-800,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-900,$my-ui-kit-color-sonic-night-disabled,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-100,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-200,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-300,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-400,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-500,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-600,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-700,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-800,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-900,$my-ui-kit-color-minion-night-disabled,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-100,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-200,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-300,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-400,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-500,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-600,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-700,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-800,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-900,$my-ui-kit-color-karl-night-disabled,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-100,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-200,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-300,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-400,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-500,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-600,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-700,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-800,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-900,$my-ui-kit-color-candy-night-disabled|}"
    }
}
```